# x86 assembly language: How can I detect the number of words in a String?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32

The code that I wrote below does not work properly. It iterates through a user-input string whose address is stored in EDX in order to determine the number of words in the String. I thought it would be possible to detect the number of words in a string by counting the number of "whitespaces", but this code returns 1 less than the actual number of words in a string. Also, if a user types in only whitespaces, the value returned is not accurate at all. How can I alter this code to accurately determine the number of words in a String.

```
 getNumWords PROC

    push    edx
    mov eax,0                  

L1: cmp BYTE PTR [edx],0       
    je  L3                   
    cmp BYTE PTR [edx]," "     
    je      L2
    inc     edx                    
    jmp     L1                    

L2: inc edx
    cmp BYTE PTR [edx]," " 
    je      L2
    cmp BYTE PTR [edx],0       ;handles - user enters only whitespaces
    je  L3                   
    inc     edx                  
    inc eax                  
    jmp L1

L3: pop edx
    mov     outputVal, eax           
    ret

getNumWords ENDP
```

Comment: If you manually count the words and space characters in the sentence "foo bar baz" you will notice that it has three words but only two spaces. There's your off-by-one. As to what to do with multiple spaces, you would need to count *runs* of whitespace, not just individual characters.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the "runs" of whitespace. I apologize for that, I'm new to assembly.

Comment: I've updated the code in my original post. I have figured out the way to detect a user entering nothing but whitespaces, but am still having trouble figuring out how to detect a word at the very end of a String. For example, if I type in "Hi there!", the function's output will still be one and not two. Any suggestions on how to remedy this?

Comment: You don't need a separate check for "whitespace only". The smart algorithm for this would be to keep track of the previous character in a variable, and increment your counter when you see a non-whitespace character after a whitespace character. Set it up so that the character "before the start of the string" is whitespace. This would handle extra whitespace, all whitespace, empty strings, everything.

Comment: Ah, I see. I believe I understand now, thank you.

Comment: The algorithm and its implementation in asm are two separate things.  Think the problem through at a high level, then implement in asm.  You will often notice modifications to the algorithm that give the same result but make the asm implementation more efficient, but try to keep in mind what your asm "means" at a high level.